# Filter on Queues Tab RabbitMQ management UI not working

Tags: rabbitmq

Filter only works for **Name** column

And i am **not** able to filter by **State, Ready, Node** etc, it shows zero rows

[image]

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am using below steps to filter & check massive queues.

1. Right click ui table
2. click inspect
3. edit html table & copy whole html table
4. go to excel& paste html table
5. add filters